# JAVA SOCKETS client server application

Tags: java, sockets, client-server

I wrote this simpel JFRAME program it consists  of two classes: Client and Server.

the server recieves text from client and prints it.

i just started learning it though so i dont really know what the problem is.

i guess the problem is the while loop or the way i get input.
please tell me what i did wrong and how to fix it :)

here is the server:

```
import java.awt.Event;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.beans.EventHandler;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Server extends JFrame {
private int running =0;

    private JPanel showInformation;
    private JButton start;
    private JButton stop;
    private JTextArea infoArea;
    private JScrollPane scroll;

    private ServerSocket server;
    private Socket client;   

    private InputStreamReader IR;
    private BufferedReader BR;

public Server(){
   //setting looks of Frame
   setLayout(null);
   showInformation=new JPanel();
   start = new JButton("Start Server");
   stop=new JButton("Stop Server");
   infoArea= new JTextArea(20,27);
   infoArea.setEnabled(false);
   infoArea.setEditable(false);
   scroll = new JScrollPane(infoArea);
   scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
   scroll.setBounds(25,10,325,200);
   scroll.setEnabled(true);
   add(scroll);

   showInformation.setSize(300, 200);
   showInformation.setBounds(25,5,325,200);
   add(showInformation);
   infoArea.setLineWrap(true);
   start.setBounds(25,225,150,50);
   stop.setBounds(200,225,150,50);

   add(start);
   add(stop);     
   //events stuff
   eventHandler handler = new eventHandler();
   start.addActionListener(handler);
   stop.addActionListener(handler);

   //sockets 
      }

   public void printOnScreen(String m){
    infoArea.append("\n"+m);
  }

  public class eventHandler implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource()==start){
           if(isServerRunning()){
               printOnScreen("Server already running");
           }
           else{
               try{
               startServer();
               }catch(Exception e1){

               }
           }
        }else 
          if(e.getSource()==stop){
              if(isServerRunning()){
                   try{
                   stopServer();
                  }catch(Exception e1){

                  }
               }
               else{
                   printOnScreen("Server Not Running yet");
               }
          }

    }

}



public boolean isServerRunning(){
    if(running==1)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}


public void startServer() throws Exception{
    server = new ServerSocket(4444);
    client = server.accept();
    IR = new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream());
    BR = new BufferedReader(IR);
    printOnScreen("Server started..");
    getMessages();
}

public void stopServer() throws Exception{
    try{
      server.close();
      client.close();
      IR.close();
      BR.close();
      printOnScreen("Server stopped..");
    }catch(Exception e1){

    }
}

private void getMessages() throws IOException{
    String M = BR.readLine();
    while(true){
        if(M!=null){
            printOnScreen(M);
        }
        M = BR.readLine();
    }
}


public static void main(String[]args){
   Server s = new Server();
   s.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   s.setSize(385, 350);
   s.setVisible(true);
   s.setTitle("      ----Server----");
   s.setTitle("Server Manager");
}
```

}

here is the client:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import javax.swing.*;

public class client1 extends JFrame{
private int connected = 0;
private JTextArea txt;
private JTextField mText;
private JButton sendMessage;
private JScrollPane scroll;
private JButton connect;
private JButton disconnect;
private Socket socket;
private ObjectInputStream input;
private ObjectOutputStream output;

public client1(){
    setLayout(null);

    txt = new JTextArea();
    scroll = new JScrollPane(txt);
    scroll.setBounds(25,10,325,200);
    add(scroll);


    mText = new JTextField();
    mText.setBounds(25,220,250,30);
    add(mText);

    sendMessage=new JButton("Send");
    sendMessage.setBounds(280,220,70,30);   
    add(sendMessage);

    connect= new JButton("Connect");
    connect.setBounds(25,260,100,30);
    add(connect);

    disconnect = new JButton("Disconnect");
    disconnect.setBounds(135,260,100,30);
    add(disconnect);
  //events stuff
       eventHandler handler = new eventHandler();
       sendMessage.addActionListener(handler);
       connect.addActionListener(handler);
       disconnect.addActionListener(handler);
   }
public class eventHandler implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource()==sendMessage){
            if(connected==1){
              try {
                sendMessage();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            }
        }
        else
            if(e.getSource()==connect){
               connected=1;
               printOnScreen("connected");
            }
        else
            if(e.getSource()==disconnect){
                connected=0;
                printOnScreen("Disconnected");
            }
    }
}

public void printOnScreen(String m){
    txt.append("\n"+m);
}

public void sendMessage() throws IOException{
    String message = mText.getText();
    txt.append("\nclient1:  "+message);
    output.writeObject(message);

}
public void connect() throws UnknownHostException, IOException{
    socket = new Socket("localhost",4444);
    output = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    output.flush();
}

public static void main(String[]args){
    client1 c1Frame = new client1();
    c1Frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    c1Frame.setSize(385,350);
    c1Frame.setTitle("             ---___Client1___---");
    c1Frame.setVisible(true);
}

  }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please note that tags stand alone.  That is, combining `client` and `server` doesn't mean the same thing as `client-server`.  Please be sure to select your tags with care.

Comment: I don't see any actual question here.

Answer (score 0):

You must be getting a NullPointerExpection. That is because you never call your connect function at the client when the connect button is clicked. So there is no Socket Connection being established because of which your output object is Null, and you can't send anything.

Comment: true i got other problem though
now i fixed it and still it just freez